# The Stack Exchange network is still using HTTP for Google fonts

Tags: discussion, ssl

Since Stack Exchange sites are moving towards [HTTPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure) I was wondering why some pages still use http and not https or // for the Google fonts links or if this is just something that's been missed? For example the [10m page](https://stackoverflow.com/10m).

Comment: That page is not such a good example because it'll be gone long before SSL is fully supported.

Comment: SSL when loading fonts would slow down the loading speed with unnecessary encryption. It's not needed.

Comment: @jyoon wouldn't you get a "mixed content" warning if you loaded them over HTTP though?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Since Stack Exchange sites are moving towards HTTPS I was wondering why some pages still use http and not https or // for the Google fonts links or if this is just something that's been missed?

Because HTTPS support is still a work in progress. We're upgrading parts of the code as we go along. For example, [user avatars are served over HTTPS now](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/636942821543542784).

We should use protocol-relative URLs more, I agree, but in practice it doesn't particularly matter for one-off temporary things like the 10m page considering that we don't fully support HTTPS yet.

Comment: Yeah I know I just thought sites like google fonts could be moved over sitewide considering there's a https version for it so using https or protocol-relative URLs wouldn't affect anything and would fix pages like that.

Comment: @XO All the assets we use will eventually use the appropriate protocol. That's (part of) the plan. :)