# Favicons in the stats widget on beta sites don't use HTTPS

Tags: bug, status-completed, beta-sites, ssl, favicon

The favicons for Area 51 and Stack Exchange that are shown on sites marked "beta" in the Site Stats widget are using `http://` URLs for favicons when visiting the sites over HTTPS.

[image: stats widget]

> Mixed Content: The page at '...' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image '...'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.

These are the links requested:

- http://area51.stackexchange.com/favicon.ico
- (redirects): http://sstatic.net/area51/img/favicon.ico
- https://stackexchange.com/favicon.ico
- (redirects): http://sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/favicon.ico

They should be using something protocol-agnostic.

Comment: +1 another good find and you notice that images/icons are now served from CDN location and that's also in the plan

Comment: @HackerKarma I may have been bugging the devs privately about this for a couple of months beforehand :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A fix will go out for this shortly.  We try and fix https issues as they come up, however we haven't performed a full audit of all urls.  HackerKarma is right, it's part of the "plan".

Answer (score 1):

I agree with you that SE should be using something protocol-agnostic. As per the [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/264367/the-stack-exchange-network-is-still-using-http-for-google-fonts/264448#264448) given by Adam Lear: (copied only relevant part)

> Because HTTPS support is still a work in progress. We're upgrading
> parts of the code as we go along. For example, [user avatars are served
> over HTTPS now](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/636942821543542784).
>
> We should use protocol-relative URLs more, I agree,

Also from the comments:

> All the assets we use will eventually use the appropriate protocol.
> That's (part of) the plan. :)

So, basically, it's a work-in-progess and that's good news.

Comment: I'm... confused why this needed to be an answer. Isn't the crux of it simply "it will happen eventually"?

Comment: @hichris123 I did not get it... I have seen few questions similar to this issue. The best thing I can do is at least share my findings about the issue. I have seen many high reps. do the similar.