# HTTPS favicons on beta sites still use HTTP

Tags: bug, status-completed, beta-sites, ssl, favicon

Directly related to [my last meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/264597/favicons-in-the-stats-widget-on-beta-sites-dont-use-https) that was [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) – the favicons on beta sites for the site stats widget doesn't actually use HTTPS, but redirects down to HTTP instead, resulting in the same issue as before.

```
https://stackexchange.com/favicon.ico -> http://sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/favicon.ico
```

Here's a curl fetch with trimmed headers:

```
➜  ~  curl -v https://stackexchange.com/favicon.ico
*   Trying 104.16.14.128...
* Connected to stackexchange.com (104.16.14.128) port 443 (#0)
* TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
> GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1
> Host: stackexchange.com
> 
< HTTP/1.1 302 Redirect
< Server: cloudflare-nginx
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Location: http://sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/favicon.ico
< 
<head><title>Document Moved</title></head>
<body><h1>Object Moved</h1>This document may be found <a HREF="http://sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/favicon.ico">here</a></body>
```

Comment: stackexchange.com is a beta site?

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young this is the more site stats table on the right of the screen, which shows the area51 + stackexchange favicons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been fixed, and will be available in the following builds:

- SE.com: build 2911
- Area 51: build 376
- MSE/MSO: build 3737
- other Stack Exchange sites: build 2860